# I cannot find my system settings icon

Tags: system-settings

I do not know what it is called. But I am missing the gear and wrench icon that come with Ubuntu and hangs out in the launch bar.

It's not anything advanced. It's like Windows Control Panel. From there you can change things like display and printer settings. I do not know what to ask for. All searches bring up much more advanced stuff or nothing at all. I want to get it back.

Any one help ? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Settings app not appearing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1370156/settings-app-not-appearing)

Answer (score 4):

- Right Click on Desktop
- Click on Open Terminal or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- Then run `sudo apt install gnome-control-center`

Answer (score 0):

Can you launch a Terminal session? From the Terminal, you can run the command to launch the settings:
`unity-control-center`

What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Can you see the sidebar?

Comment: After you've launched the Systems Settings window using the command `unity-control-center`, right-click the System Settings icon and select *Lock to Launcher* from the popup menu to lock the Systems Settings icon to the launcher.

Comment: this does not give the functionality of logging out or suspending though.