# Settings app not appearing

Tags: updates, system-settings

I am not able to locate Settings in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
I have been using Ubuntu for the last 1 year but it is not visible to me now.
Don't know what is happening.
Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

First you need to check whether you accidentally uninstalled your system settings app.

Try running:

```
whereis gnome-control-center
```

If the result is showing a path, then your settings app package is not removed and you can open it from terminal by executing:

```
gnome-control-center
```

Then the app may be accidentally removed somehow from your shell menu, which you can be fixed using a menu editor like menulibre. You may refer to this answer to know more about it: [How to edit the Applications Menu in GNOME 3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/792067/how-to-edit-the-applications-menu-in-gnome-3)

Else, if `whereis` didn't return a path and returned something like this:

```
gnome-control-center:
```

you somehow got the package removed from your system, so do reinstall it using `apt`:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install gnome-control-center -y
```

Hope this will solve your issue.